# Install JRE 1.7 on Mac - when version 1.8 is already installed

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have a Mac with OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5.  The current JRE installed on the Mac is 1.8.

While trying to install JRE 1.7 - the Java installer fails and will not allow the installation of an older version of JRE as the latest version is already installed.

I need the JRE 1.7 to run test on Java programs on Eclipse, to ensure compatibility on Google Platform, which only supports 1.7 as of now.

Is there a way to install JRE 1.7 and bypass the installer?  Any suggestions or workarounds?

Current (warning) on Eclipse:  Build path specifies execution env. JavaSE 1.7.  There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

Comment: download JDK and set jre 1.7 in eclipse preferences. In Eclipse, go to window>preferences>java>installed JREs, add JRE 1.7. Don't forget to set your project to compile using java 1.7. Verify if your project's build path contains JRE 1.8 library, if yes, change to 1.7 clicking on add library button.

Comment: @Johnny Willer.  Did exactly what you suggested and it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the JRE and not the JDK? I've got several versions of the JDK running on my mac, linux and windows machines.